Modify TypeScript generic function parameters and return types
Can I make all the arguments of a function readonly and convert that function to an async function?
For example:
declare function foo<T>(bar: T, baz: T[]): T;

Convert to
declare function foo<T>(bar: Readonly<T>, baz: readonly T[]): Promise<T>;

I've tried this, which works for non-generic functions:
type ReadonlyArrayItems<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Readonly<T[P]> };
type MakeFunctionAsync<T> = (...args: ReadonlyArrayItems<Parameters<T>>) => Promise<ReturnType<T>>;
type Foo = MakeFunctionAsync<typeof foo>;

However, the new function type Foo messes up the generic function by turning all the original generic type T into unknown.

P.S. Thanks for the answers.
However, is it possible to do this for all functions within an interface?
For example:
interface Methods {
    foo<T>(bar: T, baz: T[]): T;
    bar(baz: string): void;
}

Become this
interface Methods {
    foo<T>(bar: Readonly<T>, baz: readonly T[]): Promise<T>;
    bar(baz: string): Promise<void>;
}

If add another type based on the above:
type MakeFunctionsAsync<T> = {
    [functionName in keyof T]: MakeFunctionAsync<T[functionName]>;
};

There doesn't seem to be a place to fill in the generic type parameter.
type MakeFunctionsAsync<T, U> = {
    [functionName in keyof T]: MakeFunctionAsync<T[functionName]<U>>;
};

This won't work.

You cannot do this purely in the type system. For a function value like foo, you can use higher order generic function inference to transform the type.  But this does not work for an object-of-functions. See this playground link and this q/a.

You should add a generic param to the Foo:
declare function foo<T>(bar: T, baz: T[]): T;

type ReadonlyArrayItems<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Readonly<T[P]> };
type MakeFunctionAsync<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = (...args: ReadonlyArrayItems<Parameters<T>>) => Promise<ReturnType<T>>;
type Foo<T> = MakeFunctionAsync<typeof foo<T>>;

Playground
To transform an interface you could use this (note that you need to have a generic interface to transform):
type ReadonlyArrayItems<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Readonly<T[P]> };
type MakeFunctionAsync<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = (...args: ReadonlyArrayItems<Parameters<T>>) => Promise<ReturnType<T>>;

interface Methods<T>{
    foo(bar: T, baz: T[]): T;
    bar(baz: string): void;
}

type MakeFunctionsAsync<T extends Record<PropertyKey, any>> = {
    [functionName in keyof T]: MakeFunctionAsync<T[functionName]>;
};

type Foo<T> = MakeFunctionsAsync<Methods<T>>;

const foo: Foo<string> = {
    async foo(bar, baz){
        return '';
    },
    async bar(baz){
        return;
    }
}

Playground

Thanks, this worked for me. However, if I define an interface and I want to do it with all the functions in the interface, is it able to add the generic parameters? I've added it to the question and look forward to your answer.

@CmoSekil i've tried to provide a solution for an interface, please check

Wait, type Foo<T> is no longer a generic function, and there's no way to turn it back into one in the type system. You can't have a value of type Foo. I'm not sure why OP thinks it works for them, maybe they can explain?

@CmoSekil my bad, you don't need to annotate the object's method's parameters in the second example, the type applies types to signatures just fine, updated the answer
